# Is there any way I can find out what calls `__lll_lock_wait_private`

Tags: c++, perf

I am running perf with the following codes, where `$TPID` is a process I want to profile

```
perf record -F 99 -p $TPID --call-graph dwarf sleep 8
perf script -i perf.data > perf.unfold
./stackcollapse-perf.pl perf.unfold &> perf.fold
./flamegraph.pl perf.fold > perf.svg
```

From the result, I find `__lll_lock_wait_private` and `_xstat` take a long time, but I can't tell who call them from this chart.

I have been asking and searching for a while why I have this result, and seems that [it is a feature of perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922432/perf-top-result-about-nested-functions/34099915#34099915). But when I look at other's flame graph, I find no one have `__lll_lock_wait_private` and `_xstat` just above `all` like me. So I wonder if there are some ways that perf can show caller of `__lll_lock_wait_private` and `_xstat` in this case?

[image]

Comment: Try to make a flame graph on a binary built without optimizations. It should become more detailed because some functions can be inlined and therefore invisible to perf.

Comment: @ks1322 I already used `g++ -O0 -fno-inline -g t.cpp -l pthread -o tttzzz`, but it does not make any difference

Comment: Could the calls be coming from library functions?  Presumably your libc.so and libstdc++ are optimized builds.

Comment: In fact, they come from `mktime`, which is called by `run_time`. But why does it no appear above `run_time`? @PeterCordes